# Reading transactions from a file and writing them to a database table

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js and I would like to see if I'm using it correctly:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require('fs');

var connectionProps = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('connection.json', 'utf8'));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: connectionProps.host,
  user: connectionProps.user,
  password: connectionProps.password,
  database: connectionProps.database
});

connection.connect();

function checkErr(err) {
  if (err) {
    connection.end();
    throw err;
  }
}

connection.query('SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_TYPE', function(err, rows, fields) {
  checkErr(err);

  var typeNameToId = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    typeNameToId[rows[i].NAME] = rows[i].ID;
  }

  fs.readFile(process.argv[2] + '.csv', 'utf8', function(err, content) {
    checkErr(err);

    var data = [];
    var lines = content.split(/\r\n?|\n/);

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      if (lines[i].trim() === '') {
        continue;
      }

      data.push(lines[i].split(','));
      var typeName = data[data.length - 1][2];
      data[data.length - 1][2] = typeNameToId[typeName];
      var dateTokens = process.argv[2].split('-');
      data[data.length - 1].push(new Date(dateTokens[0], dateTokens[1] - 1, dateTokens[2]));
    }

    connection.query(
      'INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT, TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE) VALUES ?',
      [data],
      function(err) {
        connection.end();

        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Connection

You get your connection with the standard `mysql.createConnection` method. OK, but you also use bare JSON sub-fields to initialise it. What if they're not there? You're going to get a `ReferenceError` whent the call tries to access it. I'd advise checking that and logging the mistake.

```
function createDatabaseConnection(properties) {
    if(properties.host && properties.user && properties.pass && properties.database) {
        return mysql.createConnection({
            host: properties.host,
            user: properties.user,
            password: properties.password,
            database: properties.database
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("Could not retrieve all required details to connect to the database.");
    }
}

var connection = createDatabaseConnection(connectionProps);
```

### Naming

There are a few - not many - places where your naming could be better.

- `checkErr` - you could name this `handleErrors`, which would reflect slightly better what it does.
- Table names - are your tables really called `TRANSACTION_TYPES`, all caps? If they are, OK, there's no standard, but if you're only doing it to match the SQL caps style, you shouldn't be.
- typeNameToId`- that reads like a method name. Perhaps call this`typeIds`?

### Magic arguments

`process.argv[2]` - how do you know that what you want is always argument number 3? This might be a good point to look at implementing switches on the command line. You seem to be getting a file name here, perhaps you should use `-f filename` as the switch.

You've also got a number of array accesses which are done with magic numbers, though that's more common and not a massive issue.

### Query errors

In your second query:

```
connection.query(
  'INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT, TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID, TRANSACTION_DATE) VALUES ?',
  [data],
  function(err) {
    connection.end();

    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
);
```

You're redefining how you handle errors. If you simply pass a reference to `checkErr` (or whatever you've called it, by then) as the third argument instead of the function, you get consistent error handling. I notice your method definition here is different to that in `checkErr` - is there a reason you're closing the connection before checking if the error actually exists this time?

Comment: The reason that I close the connection before I check for an error is because I want to make sure that the connection will get closed.

Comment: @SBel so on the other hand: why do it *after* you check for the error in `checkErr`?

Comment: If I will call checkErr and there is no error then the connection won't get closed.

Comment: Fair enough. Just want to check that it's deliberate, rather than an error.